# How do I retry a failed AWS Greengrass deployment

Tags: aws-iot-greengrass

I have revised an existing deployment with a new version of the component.

However the deployment failed on a core device because there was a local deployment with a different version that was used for testing.

I have removed that local deployment and now I want to rerun the deployment on that device.

Is that possible? Or do I need to revise the existing deployment (keeping everything the same, so not really a revision)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Greengrass v2 there is no such thing as 'restart' deployment (not sure about Greengrass v1). If it fails, read the error messages in log files, fix the issue, revise the deployment with correct parameters and deploy again, or create new deployment.
Here you can find common deployment issues:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/troubleshooting.html#greengrass-core-deployment-issues